# How to pass rated row from jsp page to servlet?

Tags: forms, jsp, html-table, action

I want to pass two attributes to servlet:

1. rating value (selected radio button)
2. rated book row

This is my form :

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="RaitingServlet">
    <div>                                                                                                                                                            
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" title="trés mauvais"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" title="mauvais"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" title="moyen"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" title="bien"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" title="trés bien"/>                                                                                             
    <input type="submit"   value="voter" style=" margin-left: 15px;" class=" btn btn-warning"  />                      
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the table:

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="${booklist}">
   <tr>
      <td style=" width:  110px; color: #3278b3;">${book.ISBN}</td>
      <td style=" width:  300px; ">${book.titre}</td>
      <td style=" width:  150px;">${book.auteur}</td>                                
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

[image: picture of the table]

Comment: since all your radio's have same name so you can use `request.getParameter("rating")` ?does this help http://java2db.com/servlets/how-to-get-the-radio-button-value-in-servlet

Comment: yes this is for the first attribute 
but the problem how to pass the selected row to the servlet

Comment: It's unclear. You have one form, and (let's say) 10 rows. How is the user supposed to select the row it wants to rate? Inshort, how would you like the page to work?

Comment: for example : 
user called ''mark" likes the book at the first row he select 4 stars .
  I want to pass to the servlet the first row selected by this user and the rating 4 .

Comment: take a look at this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0kht.png

Comment: Ah, so there is one form in every row. So your table rows should have an additional cell containing the form. And you could thus easily add a hidden field in the form containing the ISBN (or other unique ID) of the book. The form shouldn't use GET, but POST.

Comment: yes thank you this what i want

Comment: @tahaseddik here is an example https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/454437/get-value-of-selected-row-from-table-jsp

Comment: yes thank you 
I forget that there is a type hidden

Comment: the solution is to add : 
<input type="hidden" name="select" value="${book.ISBN}">

and in the servlet : 
request.getParameter("rating");
request.getParameter("select")